# How to copy and paste a table but with formula

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

If I copy table and paste it into one cell, it works fine - creates table starting with cell I oasted it into.

But I want to do that with formula. For example, I fill the cell with `=A1:B2` but that doesn't work - it fills only value of cell on top left or it outputs error.

So I just need working `=A1:B2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of `=A1:B2` use:

```
={A1:B2}
```

or:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(A1:B2)
```